# changing a JS value according to media queries on vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, media-queries

I have this div below that the content changes according to the variable value of 'fullSideBar', true and false. Today, this value changes with a button.

I want to know if it is possible to change the value of 'fullSideBar' when the width medias changes. Something like: @media screen and (max-width: 768px) { this.fullSideBar = false}.

This is the code:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <img 
        src="../../../static/icons/arrow-bar-left.svg" 
        alt="Ícone de seta a esquerda" 
        class="pe-auto icon-SideBar" 
        @click="fullSideBar = !fullSideBar"
        v-if="!this.fullSideBar"
    >
    <img 
        src="../../../static/icons/arrow-bar-right.svg" 
        alt="Ícone de seta a esquerda" 
        class="pe-auto icon-SideBar" 
        @click="fullSideBar = !fullSideBar"
        v-else
    >
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import FooterSideBarVue from './FooterSideBar.vue';
export default {
    name: 'BodyScrolling',
    components: {
        FooterSideBarVue
    },
    data (){
        return {
            footerItems: [
                'Sobre'
                , 'Documentação'
                , 'Contato'
            ],
            fullSideBar: false,
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can react to the [window resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event). Reacting in JavaScript to a certain media query doesn't exist AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia#compatibilit%C3%A9_des_navigateurs) function to check in javascript if the window currently matches the given media query.

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
   this.fullSideBar = false;
}
```

To react to the window size changes, use `window.addEventListener("resize", myListener);`:

```js
function updateFullSideBar(evt) {
  // Check the innerWidth property or use window.matchMedia here too
  this.fullSideBar = evt.view.innerWidth < 768
}

window.addEventListener("resize", updateFullSideBar);
```